# AIDL implementation for Protobuf generated object

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers, parcelable, aidl

I have use case as follows, my custom object is generated from Protobuf. I would like to use these protobuf generated class as parameter for AIDL implementations.

Since protobuf doesn't use parcelable is it possible to achieve this kind of implementation by any change

here is my protobuf message

```
message Employee{
enum Department{
IT = 0;
MARKETING = 1;
}

string name = 0;
Department dept = 1;
}
```

here is my AIDL interface

```
interface IDepartmentAIDL {
Employee getEmployee(String name);
}
```

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/H6-aqX1L8YU

Comment: More https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial#parsing-and-serialization